# Exterior Angle is Being Labelled Instead of Interior in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tkz-euclide, angle, tikz-angles

So, after much painstaking research (for something that one feels should be simple) I figured out how to make angles in diagrams!  The package I'm using is `tkz-euclide`, which seems simple enough to use.

However, whenever I'm making  my force diagram, the angle is made outside the figure, instead of inside. [image: Incorrect Angle Modeled on Bottom]

Can anyone help me get the lower angle on the inside of the figure?  I understand it's probably the arrows that are confusing `tkz-euclide`, but I need them.  My entire code is below:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide} 
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    \draw[style=help lines] ;

%%  The lines for the figures, going from node to node.
\draw[thick] (-2.2,2.2) -- (0,0);
\draw[thick,->] (-2.2,2.2) -- (2,2.2);
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,-3);
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (1.5,-1.5);
\draw[thick,->] (1.5,-1.5) -- (0,-3);
\draw[thick,->] (.12,.12) -- (2,2);
\draw[thick,->] (.12,.12) -- (1.62, -1.38);
%%  First batch of coordinates for the angle with the theta.
\coordinate (A) at (-2.2,2.2);
\coordinate (B) at (2,2.2);
\coordinate (C) at (0,0);
%%  2nd batch of coordinates for the angle with the lower theta.
\coordinate (D) at (1.5, -1.5);
\coordinate (E) at (0,-3);
%%  Nodes set up for the various symbols around the figure.
\node (F) at (1.4,.9) {\(F_N\)};
\node (G) at (1.22,-.4) {\(F_\perp\)};
\node (H) at (1.13,-2.45) {\(F_\top\)};
\node (I) at (-.29, -1.50) {\(w\)};
%%  The two angles are described here.
\tkzMarkAngle[fill=orange,size=0.7,opacity=.4](C,A,B)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.45](C,A,B){\({\theta}_0\)}

\tkzMarkAngle[fill=orange,size=0.5,opacity=.4](C,E,D)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.5](C,E,D){\({\theta}_u\)}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Swap the order of the coordinates?

Comment: Yup @TorbjørnT. is right the angle is `(D,E,C)` instead of `(C,E,D)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the arrows. Which of the two possible angles is marked is determined by the order in which you specify the coordinates in `\tkzMarkAngle`. Hence, you just need to use `\tkzMarkAngle[fill=orange,size=0.5,opacity=.4](D,E,C)` instead of `\tkzMarkAngle[fill=orange,size=0.5,opacity=.4](C,E,D)`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide} 
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    \draw[style=help lines] ;

%%  The lines for the figures, going from node to node.
\draw[thick] (-2.2,2.2) -- (0,0);
\draw[thick,->] (-2.2,2.2) -- (2,2.2);
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,-3);
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (1.5,-1.5);
\draw[thick,->] (1.5,-1.5) -- (0,-3);
\draw[thick,->] (.12,.12) -- (2,2);
\draw[thick,->] (.12,.12) -- (1.62, -1.38);
%%  First batch of coordinates for the angle with the theta.
\coordinate (A) at (-2.2,2.2);
\coordinate (B) at (2,2.2);
\coordinate (C) at (0,0);
%%  2nd batch of coordinates for the angle with the lower theta.
\coordinate (D) at (1.5, -1.5);
\coordinate (E) at (0,-3);
%%  Nodes set up for the various symbols around the figure.
\node (F) at (1.4,.9) {\(F_N\)};
\node (G) at (1.22,-.4) {\(F_\perp\)};
\node (H) at (1.13,-2.45) {\(F_\top\)};
\node (I) at (-.29, -1.50) {\(w\)};
%%  The two angles are described here.
\tkzMarkAngle[fill=orange,size=0.7,opacity=.4](C,A,B)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.45](C,A,B){\({\theta}_0\)}

\tkzMarkAngle[fill=orange,size=0.5,opacity=.4](D,E,C)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.5](C,E,D){\({\theta}_u\)}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As soon are you made the comment right after I posted my question, I was shocked that that was the answer.  It would certainly help if the documentation for `tkz-euclide` was not in French.  Thanks so much, Torbjorn!